# how to get auth in guzzle response and send to view

Tags: php, laravel-6, guzzle6

I am confused how to retrieve authentication details like username and password as my guzzle api is receiving only success message and code at the time of login. I am not able to make session. Please explain how I can get authentication details in dashboard view like Auth:user();

This is my controller:

```php
<?php
    public function getGuzzleRequest(Request $request)
    {       
        $inputData = [];        
        $inputData = $request->all();
        $client = new Client([
        'allow_redirects'=>true,
        ]);
        $URI = 'http://ahlocal.test/api/login';
        $body['username']=$inputData['username'];
        $body['password']=$inputData['password'];       
        $response = $client->request('POST', $URI,[     
        'form_params' => $body,
        ]);
        $response =$response->getBody()->getContents();
        if(statuscode=='200')
        {
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood you correctly, but try this option:

```php
$client = new Client([ 'allow_redirects'=>true, ]);
$URI = 'http://ahlocal.test/api/login';
$response = $client->request('POST', $URI, [ 'auth' => [$inputData['username'], $inputData['password']]]);
$body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
if($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
    return redirect('dashboard');
} else {
    return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
}
```

Comment: i am not able to receive username in a dashboard view so how can i make authenticate,if i add auth:user in view no data showing

Comment: session is not working i have main problem for session,please help

Comment: Show the code in which you are working with the session.

Comment: @extends('layouts.app-dashboard')
@section('content')
<!-- asidebar section -->
<div class="AH-wrap">



 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 AH-wallet clearfix">
    <div class="AH-area float-right"> 
     <h4 class="text-center"> {{ Auth::user()}}</h4>
     <p class="text-center">185</p>
    </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 AH-umrah">
    <div class="AH-area">  
     <h4 class="text-center">Next Umrah</h4>
     
    </div> 
   </div>
</div> 
   </div>

Comment: here auth:user() does not receive any result,i haven't create session because what i know session will create auth so i am following that only
this is my route
Route::post('login', 'Web\UserController@getGuzzleRequest');

Comment: I do not understand how this code relates to your question. In question, you had a problem logging in from your site to another site.
I also do not recommend writing business logic in views. Use controllers for this.

Comment: yes i am moving login to dashboard but there is no session generating so page return back to login page eventhough i loged in

Comment: So i want to know how to make user authentication by using guzzle login api to dashboard with maintaining session

Comment: Why do you need Guzzle? Why not just do that:
```
if (Auth::attempt([
            'email'    => request('username'),
            'password' => request('password'),
        ])) {
return redirect('dashboard');
} else {
    return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
}
```

Comment: that detail already is there in this api http://ahlocal.test/api/login where its checking everything and returning success or error result you will find below
if ( Auth::attempt([ $var     => $inputData[$var], 'password' => $inputData['password'],
   'status' => 'Active', 'user_type' => $inputData['user_type'] ])
problem is its not returning auth:user() details so how i can pass this to view without any auth data